# Sum numbers in StreamWriter instead of writing next to each other in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I would like to write every data to a CSV file. Everything is working fine, but the numbers aren't adding up, they are written next to each other.

This part of the code:

```
file.WriteLine("\"1. koordinata:\"" + ";" + opening.rect_co_x + ";" + cord.y + ";" + opening.rect_co_z);
file.WriteLine("\"2. koordinata:\"" + ";" + opening.rect_co_x + opening.rect_width + ";" + cord.y + ";" + opening.rect_co_z);
```

Every property is a `double, uint` or `int`.

**What I expect:**
**1 + 3 = 4**

**What I got:**
**1 + 3 = 13**

Comment: Try enclosing the addition in parenthesis: `";" + (opening.rect_co_x + opening.rect_width) + ";"` to prevent it from doing string concatenation.

Comment: Didn't help... I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+`: mean a string concatenation, you can't calculate some of int inside string directly.
Try to use the following approach:

```
int a = 1, b = 3;
string str = $"a;{a + b};b"; // a;4;b

//or string.Format
string str2 = string.Format("a;{0};b", a + b);
```

You can change your code to:

```
file.WriteLine($"\"1. koordinata:\";{opening.rect_co_x };{cord.y};{opening.rect_co_z}");
file.WriteLine($"\"2. koordinata:\";{opening.rect_co_x + opening.rect_width};{cord.y};{opening.rect_co_z}");
```

I hope this help.